# Trying to enlarge images on an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to coding and am trying to enlarge an image onclick and then un-enlarge an image onclick, using JavaScript. I've tried using jQuery but jQuery doesn't seem to work so I'm simply using JavaScript.

This is the JavaScript:

```
var myImg1 = document.getElementById('myImg1')
var myImg2 = document.getElementById('myImg2')
var myImg3 = document.getElementById('myImg3')

myImg1.onclick = function() {
  if (myImg1.style.height = '100px') {
    myImg1.style.height = '1000px'
    return
  } else {
    myImg1.style.height = '100px'
    return
  }
}
```

The image has the class assigned 'i' in HTML and CSS, which sets the width as 100px.

The code does successfully enlarge the image to 1000px but it doesn't un-enlarge.

I've tried quite a few different methods, but mostly with jQuery and I can't get jQuery to work.

Comment: In JavaScript to test equality you need to use`==` -- `myImg1.style.height =='100px')`

Comment: Omg. Thank you so much. This was so frustrating. I can't believe I didn't remember that.

Comment: I think even seasoned Javascript programmers still get caught by that from time to time.

Comment: With Javascript problems like this, if you use a Chrome or Firefox browser, you should normally be able to see an error in your browser's console (right click > inspect (console tab). This will give you an error, the file the error happens in. You should also be able to click on the javascript file, where it will show you exactly where the error occurs. That should get you started on debugging issues like this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use 2 equal signs to compare two things, one equal sign means you are trying to set a value for that variable.

```
if (myImg1.style.height == '100px') {
    myImg1.style.height = '1000px'
    // return
}
```

as Pato Salazar mentioned in the comments the return statement isn't needed.

Comment: Yes. That is what was wrong. I just didn't think of it because enlarge was working. Thank you for answering my question

Comment: Yeah. How do I do that? This is my first post

Comment: To add to this answer, you don't have to return. The `if/else` statement is exclusive, which means that only one block is being executed. Your `return` statement is doing nothing

Comment: Ah ok. I thought that for some reason it would continue down the line and see that else is now true and do the else statement

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript:

```
var myImg1 = document.getElementById('Img1');
myImg1.onclick = function() {
    if (myImg1.style.height == '1000px') {
       myImg1.style.height = '100px';
    } else {
       myImg1.style.height = '1000px';
    }
}
```

OR

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#Img1').click(function() {
        jQuery('#Img1').toggleClass('img1_1000px');
    });
});
```

Both work. If you need jQuery, use to write < img src="Img1.jpg" id="Img1" style="height: 100px;" > and .img1_1000px { height: 1000px!important; } in style.

I hope I helped you.

Comment: Thanks thats what I initially tried. I made an 'o' class and wrote it as  $('myImg1').on('click', function() {
      $(myImg1).toggleClass('o');                                                                     but I don't think I'm loading jQuery properly so gave up on that route